# InputEvent.dataTransfer is always null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inputevent

I have the following element in my component:

```
<div className="document" contentEditable="true" placeholder="Write something...." ref={this.document} onBlur={this.onBlur} onInput={this.onInput} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: document.content}}></div>
```

And the following is the function `onInput`:

```
onInput(event) {
    event = event.nativeEvent;
    console.log(event.dataTransfer); // This is null
}
```

I want to use `dataTransfer` to figure out if something was pasted/dropped, without listening to each one's specific event, in order to have everything managed from the `InputEvent` (Because `InputEvent` fires for most actions I want to listen to already)

Even the example on MDN isn't working because `dataTransfer` is `null`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/dataTransfer

Why is this happening? Is this some standard that has not been implemented yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MDN example works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. On the other hand, in the same MDN example, listening to `beforeinput` rather than `input` works in Chrome, but not Firefox. So using a combination of the two events should work across the two browsers.

As far as I can tell, the [specification](https://w3c.github.io/input-events/#event-definitions) says the attribute should be set in both cases.